# Error message not showing in laravel

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I'm trying to get the error message to show when I attempt to login with the wrong username and password combination, so when I do that I don't get an error message showing. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

My controler

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::attempt(array('name' => Input::get('name'), 'password' => Input::get('password'))))
        {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('home')
                ->with('message', 'Your username and password combination is wrong')
                ->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```

my index.blade.php

```
@if ($errors->any())
    {{ implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) }}
@endif

<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="login-header">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="form_input">
        {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/')) }}
            <div class="form_group">
                {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
                {{ Form::text('name', '' , array("class" => "form-control")) }}
            </div>

            <div class="form_group password-section">
                {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
                {{ Form::password('password', array("class" => "form-control")) }}
            </div>

            <div class="form_group submit_button">
                {{ Form::submit('Submit', array("class" =>"btn btn-info submit", "role" => "button")) }}
            </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

My routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function()
{
    Route::get('admin/', [
        'uses' => 'HomeController@index',
        'as' => 'home'
    ]);

    Route::post('/signin', [
        'uses' => 'HomeController@login',
        'as' => 'Login'
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() in routes

Comment: I don't see how that would work because as far as I know `Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth']` is only for after you've logged in.

Comment: if auth middleware is not used then you can't authenticate a user for login on post.

Comment: I've added the Route::group and I got "Page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: for GET request or POST request ?

Comment: for the GET request

Comment: plz define get and post routes for both requests and use web for get route and use auth for post route.